# CSS gradient on border

Tags: html, css, background, border, gradient

In the following code, the gradient has a width of 100% and goes over the border on the left side.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub8LpLub/2/)

```css
input {
    background: transparent;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(164, 164, 164);
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
#demo {
    background : transparent linear-gradient(to right, rgba(109, 179, 242, 0) 0%, rgb(24, 189, 70) 100%, rgba(54, 144, 240, 0) 0%, rgba(58, 107, 182, 0) 100%);
}
body {
    background: hsla(0, 5%, 5%, 1) linear-gradient(to right top, rgba(10%, 0%, 0%, 1), rgba(0%, 0%, 0%, 1)) no-repeat fixed;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo" />
<input type="text" />
```

Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the background will extend to the border edge by default. You can avoid this by using the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) property, by setting `background-clip: padding-box;`.

### Working Example:

```css
input {
    background: transparent;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(164, 164, 164);
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
#demo {
    background : transparent linear-gradient(to right, rgba(109, 179, 242, 0) 0%, rgb(24, 189, 70) 100%, rgba(54, 144, 240, 0) 0%, rgba(58, 107, 182, 0) 100%);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
body {
    background: hsla(0, 5%, 5%, 1) linear-gradient(to right top, rgba(10%, 0%, 0%, 1), rgba(0%, 0%, 0%, 1)) no-repeat fixed;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo" />
<input type="text" />
```